# Storing Result from API Call in Data Frame through Loop in R

Tags: r, dataframe, api

I would like to store a result of an API call in a data frame. The code should loop through different time periods and countries.

If I do one example, it's like this:

```
testapicall <- jsonlite::fromJSON("https.api.companyname/jurisdiction=eu_ger&date=2018-01-01:2018-01:31&api_token=XYZ")

testapicall[["results"]]$total_number
```

Now I want to to get this "total number" for different jurisdictions and date ranges. One column should be country name, one should be the date (e.g., 01-2018), and one should be the total_number.

To set up the loop, I've split the API key into 3 parts:

```
base_string1 <- "https.api.companyname/jurisdiction="
base_string2 <- "&date="
end_string <- "api_token=XYZ"
```

Then, I can create the dates and countries the dates and countries like this:

```
dates <- seq(as.Date("1990-01-01"), as.Date("2022-01-01"), by = "month")
dates <- paste(head(dates, -1), tail(dates-1, - 1), sep = ":")

countries<- paste0("eu_", c("fra", "ger"))
```

Now, I'd like to get the results for each country-date into a data frame, but this is the part I am not sure how to do. I know I have to make an empty data frame and then fill it somehow.

```
for (y in date){
  for(c in countries){
    api_string <-  paste0(base_string1,y, base_string2,c, end_string)
    json <- jsonlite::fromJSON(api_string) 
     json[["results"]]$total_number
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map_dfr` from `purrr` to iterate over the countries and dates and generate a dataframe with a single row for each iteration. `map_dfr` will row bind all the dataframes together.

```
library(purrr)
map_dfr(dates, function(date){
    map_dfr(countries, function(country){
        api_string <-  paste0(base_string1, date, base_string2, country, end_string)
        json <- jsonlite::fromJSON(api_string)
        data.frame(country = country, 
                   date = date, 
                   total_number = json[["results"]]$total_number)
    })
})
```

Comment: Hi @AdroMine, thank you for your answer! I tried this code, and it resulted in "# A tibble: 0 x 0"

Comment: were the dates and/or countries empty? You will also have to perform the API call after creating the api_string.

Comment: Hi @AdroMine, the API call should be this part: "json <- jsonlite::fromJSON(api_string)". I don't think a data frame was created with the code, at least I didn't get something like "0 obs of 0 variables." It just said "# A tibble: 0 x 0"

Comment: Ah I think I might have found the mistake (it was mine: the jurisdiction and the date were reversed in the loop example. So the position of "date" and "country" needed to be switched). Let me see if it works now

Comment: `api_string` is just the generated URL, you will need to make an API call (you can look at httr::GET for examples) which actually fetches data from the given url.

Comment: The jsonlite::fromJSON is the API call. I ran the code and it works, thank you! But it just gives me a list. How do I now say that the results is a dataframe? I tried testdf <- data.frame(country = country,...) but this didn't work

Comment: I.e., the output looks something like this, and I am trying to figure out how to save it in a named dataframe 
countries                 dates total_number
1  eu_ger 1990-01-01:1990-12-31       6020
2  eu_fra 1990-01-01:1990-12-31       3000
3  eu_ger 1991-01-01:1991-12-31       4900
4  eu_fra 1991-01-01:1991-12-31       1400

Comment: Please post `dput` of results and not in comments. (Dput will look like gobbledygook  to you but not us). Given the `data.frame` call, you should get a binded data frame returned unless your API `total_number` may not return a single value or returns a NULL or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Consider `expand.grid` to build all possible pairwise combinations of country and month dates into data frame and then `mapply` to create a new column to retrieve the API data elementwise between each country and month range.

Also, consider a user-defined method that uses `tryCatch` (useful with API calls) to return `NA` on error and not stop on problematic urls.

```r
# INPUTS
dates <- seq(as.Date("1990-01-01"), as.Date("2022-01-01"), by="month") 
countries <- paste0("eu_", c("fra", "ger"))

# USER-DEFINED METHODS
get_api_data <- function(cnty, rng) {
    url <- paste0(
        "https.api.companyname/jurisdiction=", cnty,
        "&date=", rng, "api_token=XYZ"
    )
    tryCatch({
        api_response <- jsonlite::fromJSON(url) 
    }, error = function(e) {
        paste0(url, " : ", e)
        return(NA_real_)
    })

    return(api_response$results$total_number)
}

add.months <- function(date, n) 
    seq.Date(date, by=paste(n, "months"), length = 2)[2]

# BUILD DATA FRAME
api_results_df <- expand.grid(
  country = countries, date = dates
) |> within({
  month_add <- sapply(date, add.months, n=1) |> `class<-`("Date")
  ranges <- paste(date, month_add-1, sep=":") 
  # PASS COLUMN DATA ELEMENTWISE INTO DEFINED METHOD
  total_number <- mapply(get_api_data, cnty=country, rng=ranges)
  rm(ranges, month_add)
})
```

Comment: Hi @Parfait, I tried the code without changing it, and it gives me the same total_number for all the months (though different ones for each country). It's not the total for the year either -- it's much too large.

Comment: Did you try manually checking a few rows of data frame into API call? Comment out the `rm` to keep *ranges* column. Rerun code. Then spot check several rows passing single values into defined method: `get_api_data("row 1 country", "row 1 range")`. See if data repeats. Maybe much older ones in early 90s do but closer to now does not? Per `expand.grid` data frame is first ordered by country then date.

Comment: Hi @Parfait, thank you for your response. I've deleted older comments and will try this solution and let you know. Thank you very much for your help -- it's my first time doing this and I'm still relatively new to R