# Storing loop results in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, api, loops

I have code that a user kindly helped me with in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71539513/storing-result-from-api-call-in-data-frame-through-loop-in-r). It does exactly what I want it to, except the results are not stored in a dataframe.

```
## Setting up API Call 
base_string1 <- "https.api.companyname/jurisdiction="
base_string2 <- "&date="
end_string <- "api_token=XYZ"

## Specifying objects to loop over 
dates <- seq(as.Date("1990-01-01"), as.Date("2022-01-01"), by = "year")
dates <- paste(head(dates, -1), tail(dates-1, - 1), sep = ":")

countries<- paste0("eu_", c("fra", "ger"))

## Looping over 
map_dfr(dates, function(dates){
  map_dfr(states, function(countries){
    api_string <-  paste0(base_string1, countries, base_string2, dates, end_string)
    print(api_string)
    json <- jsonlite::fromJSON(api_string)
    data.frame("countries" = countries, 
               "dates" = dates, 
               "total_number" = json[["results"]]$total_number)
  })
})
```

This gives me

```
 countries                 dates total_number
1  eu_ger 1990-01-01:1990-12-31       2404
2  eu_fra 1990-01-01:1990-12-31       2056
3  eu_ger 1991-01-01:1991-12-31       3490
4  eu_fra 1991-01-01:1991-12-31       6070
5  eu_ger 1992-01-01:1992-12-31       7808
6  eu_fra 1992-01-01:1992-12-31       1904
```

Which is the information I want, but I'd like to store it in a dataframe that I can access. I'd also like to call the countries "Germany" and France," and rather than the date range, I'd like to call it something like 1992 (and there's also a version where I go by month, in which case I'd like the value to be the year-month).

I've tried adding the below after the API call, but without success.

```
json_df<- as_tibble(json)
json_df <- data.frame("countries" = countries, 
               "dates" = dates, 
               "total_number" = json[["results"]]$total_number)
```

How do I store the results in a dataframe, and ideally also change the country names/dates?

Comment: Hi @AndreaM, No it doesn't. The post you linked is my own (I also linked it at the top). And it works, except for the last part, where I need to save it as a dataframe.

Comment: I think you just need to assign the result. `my_results <- map_dfr(dates, ...`

Comment: Yes!! Thank you @GregorThomas! The next plot is now to make a ggplot of the total_ number for each country-year... Let me know if you have any recommendations for this (will work on figuring it out myself of course)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as suggested in the comments above try:

```
my_results <- map_dfr(dates, function(dates){
  map_dfr(states, function(countries){
    api_string <-  paste0(base_string1, countries, base_string2, dates, end_string)
    print(api_string)
    json <- jsonlite::fromJSON(api_string)
    data.frame("countries" = countries, 
               "dates" = dates, 
               "total_number" = json[["results"]]$total_number)
  })
})
```